# parse Query multiple tables, image with data

Tags: sql, parse-platform

I have a 2 tables

1. USER-username, email, fname, lname ....
2. Profile_Image: email, pic

Id linking the two tables by email

I created a fragment that shows a list of all users with all their data using Class using a simple query ..
Of course the list I created is adapted.

Now I want to add each row the image of that person but I can not do it.
Would love to get help how to create a query of this type.
Thanks to all helpers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't link them by email address... Store a Pointer to the Profile object on the User object.

Then when you query the Users class, you can `include/includeKey` the profile column and will retrieve that data too, in the same call.